# Button overlaps TabLayout in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-tablayout, android-constraintlayout

In Constraintlayout i am using guideline to show tablayout and a view, tablayout covers 10% and view covers rest of 90% of screen. On tab click i want to show some buttons coming from bottom to 55% of screen for which i am using another guideline (for widgets) at 55%.

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#D3D3D3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/glTabLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="Button"
            android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/glWidgets" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/glWidgets" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/test"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/glWidgets" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/glTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.90" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/glWidgets"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.55" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/glTabLayout"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

At start when tab is selected widgets will show like first screenshot. But on  other tab click i want these widgets to slide/animate to bottom for which i am changing guideline (for widgets) from 55% to 90% so that it hides behind the tablayout.

Code to animate/update guideline:

```
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = binding.cl;
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
    constraintSet.setGuidelinePercent(binding.glWidgets.getId(), percent);
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout);
    constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

Now imageview, textview or other normal views hide below the tablayout But Button overlaps the tablayout. I want button to come under the tablayout when animated. Screenshots are attached for better understanding:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you checked elevation settings of a button? Also, Z-translation is a subject to check

Comment: Another thing: try to add `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` to your Button, its default value causes the Button to be drawn after "static" elements

Comment: @NikitaKhlebushkin Aadding android:stateListAnimator="@null" to Button worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried typecasting the button into a textView whenever you are on that mode where you want to show tabs on top of views?

- *If you do not need much from the Button class this can be an alternative:*

Using a layout (relative or Linear) that contains a textview and an imageview instead of a button.

Comment: second option is not feasible because i dont want to use viewgroups and nested layouts, but yes using TextView instead of Button can also do the trick but in that way i will only mimic the characteristics of Button that also miss the purpose. As i want to use Button's features